# Dropdown with multiple models

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble figuring out how to select the appropriate value in a dropdown based on multiple model attributes.  I am trying to achieve a dropdown with 3 options: `Present, Absent, Make-up`.

The catch is, the absent attribute stores whether a person was absent (`true/false`), and the makeup attribute stores whether it was a make-up(IE a user was making up a class, so he was `absent: false` and `makeup: true`. For example, say I have the following model:

```
users : {
  1 : {
    absent: true
    makeup: false
  },
  2 : {
    absent: false
    makeup: true
  }
}
```

and then a dropdown with the following options:

```
options : {
   false : 'Present'
   true : 'Absent'
   'makeup' : 'Make-Up'
}
```

I know how to bind the correct values to the model based on the selection, via ng-change.  However, I'm having trouble displaying the initial value in the dropdown, since the value is dependent upon multiple model attributes:

```
// options shown in full instead of ng-options for demo purposes here
<select ng-model="user.absent">
    <option value="false">Present</option>
    <option value="true">Absent</option>
    <option value="makeup">Make-up</option>
</select>
```

This is driving me up a wall! Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is the best solution I could come up with.  It's a bit ugly, but it works  I'm still looking for a more proper solution, if anyone has one.

```
<select ng-model="userAttendance.status" ng-change="changeAttendance(userAttendance)">
     <option value="false" ng-selected="userAttendance.makeup == false && userAttendance.absent == false">Present</option>
     <option value="true" ng-selected="userAttendance.absent == true">Absent</option>
     <option value="makeup" ng-selected="userAttendance.makeup == true && userAttendance.absent == false">Make-up</option>
</select>

//controller
$scope.changeAttendance = function(userAttendance) {
    if (userAttendance.status == 'makeup') {
       userAttendance.makeup = true;
       userAttendance.absent = false;
    } else {
       userAttendance.absent = userAttendance.status;
       userAttendance.makeup = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: can both be true or both be false?

Comment: I don't see a scenario where both would be true.  If user was present and making up, absent = false and makeup = true.  If user is absent, user cant be making up, so absent = true, makeup = false. However, both could be false if user is present but not making up... absent = false, makeup = false.

Comment: Then why do you have 3 options - 2 should suffice, no?

Comment: No, because the database stores absent/present in one column, and whether it was a make-up in another.  That way it's easy to see # of present users, and # of users making up.  So when "Make-Up" is selected, it's setting the makeup attribute to true, as well as present = true(absent=false).

Comment: That's fine, but why do you have 3 drop down options? Looks Makeup would always appear instead Present (or vice versa).

Comment: What happens in the event that a user is Present, but not making up a class?  makeup = false.... I prematurely answered your first question, and amended it afterwards... both options could be false.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution I could come up with.  It's a bit ugly, but it works  I'm still looking for a more proper solution, if anyone has one.

```
<select ng-model="userAttendance.status" ng-change="changeAttendance(userAttendance)">
     <option value="false" ng-selected="userAttendance.makeup == false && userAttendance.absent == false">Present</option>
     <option value="true" ng-selected="userAttendance.absent == true">Absent</option>
     <option value="makeup" ng-selected="userAttendance.makeup == true && userAttendance.absent == false">Make-up</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.changeAttendance = function(userAttendance) {
    if (userAttendance.status == 'makeup') {
       userAttendance.makeup = true;
       userAttendance.absent = false;
    } else {
       userAttendance.absent = userAttendance.status;
       userAttendance.makeup = false;
    }
};
```